# Does MySQL support data structures (such as AVL tree or Heap)?

Tags: mysql, data-structures, time-complexity

I have studied some data structures in Java but basically, I am a web developer and I use MySQL database in my PHP applications. I wonder if we use any data structures especially AVL tree or Heap in the web application. I do know MySQL uses its own algorithm for searching and does the time complexity it follow is of binary search tree which is O(log n)??

Comment: Well, data structures can be implemented in any language including PHP.

Comment: You might want to check out [PHP SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php). Specifically, http://php.net/manual/en/class.splheap.php As stated, data structures can be implemented in many languages.